# Filter greater than and length angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need length of books that added after item, here is my controller:

```
$scope.items = [
    {"added_days_ago": 5, "books": [{"id":1, "added_days_ago": 6}, {"id":2, "added_days_ago": 3}, {"id":3, "added_days_ago": 4}]},          
    {"added_days_ago": 2, "books": [{"id":4, "added_days_ago": 3}]}
]
```

In controller i need to define filteredBooksLength (i using ng-table) and then show like:

```
{{filteredBooksLength}}
```

Something like:

```
filteredBooksLength = (books where book.added_days_ago > item.added_days_ago).length
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmszapuq/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.filteredBooksLength = function (item) {
  return item.books.filter(function (book) {
    return book.added_days_ago > item.added_days_ago
  }).length
```

Should cover your needs - summon it within the `ng-repeat` block, and pass in the current item - `filteredBooksLength(item)`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94g3krt8/1/)

#### How it works

We're giving the scope access to a function that accepts an item object as an argument. We take the `books` array on that object and pass it though a `filter` function, which returns only those books where `book.added_days_ago` is greater than `item.added_days_ago` as an array. We then measure the length of that array and return it.

#### Note on style

From what you've written - and the way you've phrased your question - it looks like you've done some Python. It's accepted practice in JS to use camelCase rather than snake_case - you may wish to change that for the the keys in your `items` object. In addition, the `""` around those keys are superfluous.

Keep at it!